# Is there any function for multiplying two voltage waveforms in LTspice?

Tags: ltspice

Does LTspice have such functionality? I want to multiply two voltage waveforms with each other by an ideal multiplier. How to construct such a multiplier? Is that even possible?

Comment: when doing transient analysis just write a*b to get the multiplied waveform.

Comment: LTspice has sources that can output a voltage/current based on a mathematical expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a 'bv' element, for example (the trace in pink is V(Va) * V(Vb)):
[image]

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to @Renan's answer, there is a builtin A-device that performs that function, and I dare say it does it better (depending on the requirements): [the (m)OTA](http://ltwiki.org/?title=Undocumented_LTspice#OTA).

As seen in the linked page, its tranfer function is `(ref - V(1,2))*V(3,4)`, where the numbers represent the pins and `ref` the internal reference parameter, default 0. Note that pin `1` is an inverting input, and `2` is non-inverting, unlike `3` (+) and `4` (-). The advantage is has over the behavioural source is that it doesn't need tinkering with `tripdv` and `tripdt` like a behavioural source, and their dynamic range [is better](http://ltspicegoodies.ltwiki.org/rants.html) (see the intro). They also have a builtin `tanh()` limit, which can be asymmetric, or not, and a few other settings, which make them the cornerstone of the opamps in the default library. All in all, unless the expression is more complicated, I would recommend the OTA over the behavioural sources anytime. For some more description see [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/444377/95619) answer. In addition, here's the same example as in the other answer, but with OTA:

[image: mota]

The upper one, `V(x)`, uses the `linear` flag, which means the output is simply `a*b`. The 2nd, `V(y)`, uses `iout`, which  makes its output symmetrically limited to an internal `tanh()`, while the 3rd, `V(z)`, has the same `tanh()` limitter but asymmetric.

One minor note: in LTspice, current sources are superior to their voltage counterparts in terms of convergence (and even speed sometimes), so instead of using a `bv`, try the alternative `bi`, or `bi2`, with the appropriate `Rpar` set. These, together with `Cpar`, can overcome even very sharp transitions which could cause `timestep too small` erros, or convergence issues.