# How do I simulate an analog multiplier in LTspice?

Tags: ltspice, multiplier

I need to perform the squaring of two input voltages and I'm not sure how to go about that without a multiplier.

Comment: does this help? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/499569/is-there-any-function-for-multiplying-two-voltage-waveforms-in-ltspice

Answer (score 2):

You can use analog multiplier IC's like [AD633](https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/simulation-models/spice-models.html)

It's spice model is available in Analog devices website.Please import the same to LTSpice.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do a search for analog multiplier and you will find results.

One method that comes to mind is the Gilbert cell. W2AEW did a good YouTube video on the Gilbert cell. Check that out.